# HDFS as Deep-Storage: Druid is not storing the historical data on hdfs

Tags: druid

I have set up a micro-server of Druid on on-prem machine. I want to use HDFS as deep-storage of druid. I have used the following [Druid Docs](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/hdfs.html), [[druid-hdfs-storage] fully qualified deep storage path throws exceptions](https://github.com/apache/incubator-druid/issues/6820) and [imply-druid docs](https://docs.imply.io/on-prem/deploy/cluster) as references.

I have made following changes in */apache-druid-0.16.0-incubating/conf/druid/single-server/micro-quickstart/_common/common.runtime.properties*

```
druid.extensions.loadList=["druid-hdfs-storage", "druid-kafka-indexing-service", "druid-datasketches"]

#
# Deep storage
#

# For local disk (only viable in a cluster if this is a network mount):
#druid.storage.type=local
#druid.storage.storageDirectory=var/druid/segments

# For HDFS:
druid.storage.type=hdfs
druid.storage.storageDirectory=hdfs://mycluster:8020/druid/segments


#
# Indexing service logs
#

# For local disk (only viable in a cluster if this is a network mount):
#druid.indexer.logs.type=file
#druid.indexer.logs.directory=var/druid/indexing-logs

# For HDFS:
druid.indexer.logs.type=hdfs
druid.indexer.logs.directory=hdfs://mycluster:8020/druid/indexing-logs
```

I have also tried **druid.storage.storageDirectory=hdfs://mycluster:9000/druid/**

But the issue is that the datasource seems to be working fine and there is no error/issue in the logs either but **I am not able to see the segments on hdfs**. I have waited for few hours(~appox 5 hrs) for data to be persisted.

Also, I have placed the Hadoop configuration XMLs (core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, yarn-site.xml, mapred-site.xml) on the classpath of my Druid node.I have copied them into */apache-druid-0.16.0-incubating/conf/druid/single-server/micro-quickstart/_common/*

> Hadoop version is 2.7.3 and druid version is 0.16.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by changing the hdp.version in the mapred-site.xml manually. I was getting following exception in middleManager.log

> **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to parse '/hdp/apps/${hdp.version}/mapreduce/mapreduce.tar.gz#mr-framework' as a URI, check the setting for mapreduce.application.framework.path**

But Still the segment metadata is showing **Request failed with status code 404.**

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any segments in the "Segments" tab of the Druid UI? If so, you can check where that segment is located in your deep storage, by click magnifying glass icon in the segment row.

[image]

The window that appears will show you segment's metadata and the path to that segment in "loadSpec" -> "path" field.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Artem, The segment metadata is showing **Request failed with status code 404**.

Comment: Hi @NikhilPandey, try "View raw" button on the right upper corner of metadata windown

Comment: The "View raw"  button is disabled.