# Access local storage for druid

Tags: druid

How do I access or view the local storage for druid? I would like to view the segments or copy the segments to a file. I am running druid operator on kubernetes. I have tried exec commands for historicals pods and middle managers pod however I am unable to enter in to any of the druid pod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried looking where the deep storage says

> Deep storage is where segments are stored. It is a storage mechanism
> that Apache Druid does not provide. This deep storage infrastructure
> defines the level of durability of your data, as long as Druid
> processes can see this storage infrastructure and get at the segments
> stored on it, you will not lose data no matter how many Druid nodes
> you lose. If segments disappear from this storage layer, then you will
> lose whatever data those segments represented.

Source: [Deep Storage on Druid documentation](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/dependencies/deep-storage.html)

For example, you have to know what directory is pointed in: `druid.storage.storageDirectory`

Remember that the data is saved in segments as we can read here: [Segments on Apache Druid documentation](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/design/segments.html)

Useful Documentation:

1. [Ingestion troubleshooting FAQ](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/ingestion/faq.html)
2. [HDFS as Deep-Storage: Druid is not storing the historical data on hdfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59155685/hdfs-as-deep-storage-druid-is-not-storing-the-historical-data-on-hdfs)
3. [Druid Setup with HDFS](https://groups.google.com/g/druid-development/c/8u5orNnQlwE?pli=1)
4. [Change Local Storage to S3 as deepstorage](https://www.druidforum.org/t/druid-cluster-local-deep-storage-mounted-as-a-same-shared-folder-on-realtime-and-historical-nodes/806)